# Failed uploading iPA in Testflight

Tags: ios, testflight, xcode11

I am using xcode11.6 and having Apple Developer account ($99). I wanted to upload iPa in TestFlight. I signed the application in xcode and tried to upload using Xcode. During uploading, the macbook pro laptop is automatically restarted. i tried more than many times.

The macbook is automatically restarting even if i tried through "xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file "path/to/application.ipa" --username "YOUR_ITMC_USER" --password "YOUR_ITMC_PASSWORD"
and aslo through Transporter app.

Kindly help me to upload the ipa in testflight.

Comment: "*the macbook pro laptop is automatically restarted.*" This isn't typical behavior. To me, this sounds like an issue completely unrelated to uploading to TestFlight.

Comment: This restart is happening all the time when the ipa uploads to Testflight. I checked too many times. IS there any other issue causing the crash?